# Converting .GHO to .vmdk

Tags: vmware, norton-ghost, ghost-image

I am trying to convert a ghost image file of a drive to a VMware disk image.  I am following the command [found here](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/converting-image-file-format-gho-vmdk-and-vmdk-gho) and get the following error (made 2 attempts):

[image]

I can't find much in the way of solutions on the web, so I was hoping someone here would know what would cause it to be considered an invalid source drive, as I know it's a valid ghost image created with Ghost 11.5.  Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you should be using mode=restore if I am reading that article right. Have you tried using restore and do you get the same error?

```
Ghost32 -clone,mode=restore,src=Drive_D.GHO,dst=DriveD.vmdk -batch -sure
```

Comment: Wow, that is correct.  In my haste I must have glanced at the wrong command when typing it in and then didn't notice it on subsequent read-throughs >_<.  It appears to be working correctly now. Thanks.

Comment: Great to hear, I think we are all susceptible to doing that.